# How do you create grass?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

If you were using a plane as a terrain, how would you add grass to the plane and make it bend and flow like there was wind. Also, how would you make the grass color vary in shades of green so you would get yellow, dry patches of grass.

Comment: There are a number of great tutorials for making grass, one of which can be found here: http://thenatureacademy.blenderguru.com/fe/18406-realistic-grass-tutorial

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done with a *Hair particle system*.

1. Add a hair particle system to your mesh:

   [image]
2. If you want to simulate the hair dynamics with realistic wind, you can use a *Smoke simulation*:

   1. Add a *smoke domain* object and a *Smoke Flow* object
   2. Add a *Wind* force field and a *Turbulence* force field (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*Add > Force field*)
   3. Adjust the settings until you have a nice simulation (optionally add some collision objects) and bake the smoke
   4. Disable the *Wind* and *Turbulence* force fields for the particle system in *Particles > Field Weights*:

      [image]
   5. Add a *Smoke Flow* force field and select the smoke domain object for the domain.
   6. Enable *Dynamics* in the particle system and increase the *Stiffness*
   7. Bake the particles, then hide the smoke domain and emitter:

[image]

As for the color variation, you could use a *Procedural texture*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: how do you change the density of the grass?

Comment: @qwertyk31 The *Number* setting at the top of the particle system. Note that this will increase heaviness of the simulation a lot, you may instead want to add child particles in *Particles > Children*. (I get nice results with *Interpolated*)