# How to make lumpy grass

Tags: modeling

I've been trying to find a way to make lumpy things like in the example image. My attempt looks bad, how can I make this?

[image: lumpy grass example image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Could you show your best result? It would be helpful in order to give you the right advice: there are many possible way to achieve such effect.

Comment: I dont have a screenshot but i made it with metaballs and it didnt look so smooth and one time i just tried to make it by hand and move every vertice ,it looked ok but it cost me to much vertices

Comment: do you want your shape to stay cartoony (i.e. non realistic)? because you can simply make a square, subdivide it, give it a solidify modifier and pull down some vertices...

Comment: yeah i want a cartoony style, but i cant get the transition. It always looks like different objects and not so smooth

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5577/how-do-you-create-grass Once you have the standard grass, you can play with the parameters to make it lumpy, unevenly distributed and so on.

Comment: @Sava I don't think that answer has much to do with this question

Comment: @WhatAMesh Erf, you're right. He posted his comment about wanting a cartoony style while I was looking around for that tutorial...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way (well in my example my salad looks like cheese but it's just a bit of displacements):

- Create a circle and extrude it several times to make several concentric circles.
- Give it a *Solidify* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Press *Smooth* in the <kbd>T</kbd> panel.
- Drag down the external circles of your mesh.
- Extrude down some of the peripheral vertices.

[image]

Comment: That's OK, their salad looks like cheese, too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add Cube and make it the size you want the grass to be
2. Add Loop cuts with CTRL+R
3. Add a Subsurf Modifier
4. Drag the vertice of the middle loop cut
5. Dissolve the edges as shown in the image
6. If done, apply the modifier
7. Select the faces you want for each color
8. Press CTRL+P to make a mesh from selection
9. Apply the desired material to your mesh

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]